# Can I use "though" instead of "nevertheless"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, expressions

This is part of my book review of [*Jak létají?*](http://www.academia.cz/autori/rudolf-dvorak.html):

> The only bad thing is that sometimes there were sentences I couldn’t
>   understand after reading them four times, so maybe I’ll get back to
>   the book in a few years and see if I’ve had got further in my
>   understanding of the world.
>
> **Though**, whether you’ll complain about the unbearable amount of
>   information stuffed up into a single sentence or wheter you’ll wonder
>   at the beauty of the elegant expression, I can recommend you the book
>   Jak létají just for the amazing depictions of the laws of the universe
>   in dialog with technology.

In the text, I use "*though*" to say "*either way, here's what we can definitely agree upon*". I think I've already seen "*though*" used in a similar meaning but some people corrected me when I tried to use it myself.

Is it OK to use "*though*" in the given context?

If anything else is wrong with the question, please edit it.

Comment: It doesn't sound fluent to me.  I don't think you actually need either *though* or *nevertheless* there, because *whether* already kind of fulfills their function.  We use *though* or *although* to compare contrasting things: *Though he is old, he is still strong.*  In your sentence you're not comparing anything contrasting - *whether you'll complain or wonder* is not being compared with any other idea, so there isn't really a place for *though* there.

Comment: Possibly useful reference: http://www.freelancewritinggigs.com/2012/03/can-you-use-though-to-begin-a-sentence/

Comment: @stangdon *Though* expresses contrast with the last sentence. So the maximally reduced sentence would sound like this: The only bad thing is that sometimes there were sentences. Though, even if you’ll complain, I can recommend you the book.

Comment: @stangdon The article says nothing about using [though -comma- sentence]. Does it mean it's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> Though, whether you’ll complain about the unbearable amount of
>   information stuffed up into a single sentence or wheter you’ll wonder
>   at the beauty of the elegant expression, I can recommend you the book
>   Jak létají just for the amazing depictions of the laws of the universe
>   in dialog with technology.

Let's reverse the order of the sentence:

> I can recommend the book for the amazing depictions of the laws of the
>   universe in dialog with technology, {though} whether you will complain
>   about the unbearable amount of information stuffed into a single
>   sentence or whether you will wonder at the beauty of the elegant
>   expression...

As you can see, you have not formed a full sentence with **though**, which functions analogous to **yet**.  We are still waiting for the other shoe to fall, for the main clause.

So you must use a word other than **though**.  You want a connector like "regardless of" or "even if".

> ... regardless of whether you will complain ... or whether you will
>   wonder.
>
> ... even if you will complain ... or if you will wonder.

Or you can simply drop **though**.

> I can recommend the book, whether you will complain or whether you
>   will wonder at...
>
> Whether you will complain ... or whether you will wonder at ..., I can
>   recommend the book.

And if you want a contrast with the prior sentence:

> **However**, I can recommend the book, whether...
>
> **That said**, I can recommend the book, whether...
>
> **Nonetheless**, I can recommend the book, whether ...

Comment: Though expresses contrast with the sentence before. So the maximally reduced sentence would sound like this: The only bad thing is that sometimes there were sentences. Though, even if you’ll complain, I can recommend you the book.

Comment: You're opting for the "even if" alternative, which is fine. But for "maximally reduced", we simply drop **though**  and leave out a connector like "even if". You need to provide both alternatives, complain/wonder at.  You can substitute "however" for "though".

Comment: So are you saying my usage of "though" is fine?

Comment: A shortened version:  *The only bad thing is that there were sentences I couldn't understand ... { **though | although | but** }  I can recommend the book { **nonetheless, in spite of that, anyway**} for its amazing depictions.* At that point, how your *whether*-clauses will integrate with the foregoing is not perfectly clear: whether you will complain about .... or whether you will wonder at ....